# query with IF not working

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi I have some variables which are calculated with API's in an early script but successfully return the value $TotalDistance (based on postcode to postcode driving distances).

I have added a checkbox to tick when it is a return journey, the idea is that it then doubles the distance, this is my query.

```
if($values['Return']>0) $TotalDistance=2*$TotalDistance; else $TotalDistance=$TotalDistance;
```

However the result is still returning as a single (x1) value even if checkbox is ticket?  Why

Comment: I think you are not  passing the right value in the condition so you will always get the value given in the {else} condition. There is nothing wrong with your code.@Johannes propose you to use and other form to write the if statement but the problem is not there.

Comment: Could you show us the code for `$values['Return']` because the problem most likely has to do with that part

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is a HTML form and $values is either a reference to, or built from $_POST.

When submitting a checkbox in an HTML form, there are two possible outcomes:

1. Unchecked - doesn't get submitted and won't be part of the array
2. Checked - the VALUE of the checkbox gets submitted

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Result" value="MyResultValue" />
<input type="hidden" name="HidValue" value="OtherValue" />
```

Would yield this when unchecked:

```
array (size=1)
    'HidValue' => string 'OtherValue' (length=10)
```

And when checked:

```
array (size=2)
    'Result' => string 'MyResultValue' (length=13)
    'HidValue' => string 'OtherValue' (length=10)
```

So, to check if it is checked (I like to include a validation check to make sure the value wasn't changed) do something like this:

```
$values = $_POST; //again I'm assuming something like this is happening
if( isset($values['Result']) && $values['Result'] == 'MyResultValue' )
```

If you don't care about the validation - just use the isset.